# How to toggle location bar format in Nautilus?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, nautilus

In a previous version of Nautilus the location had a button for toggling between a text field for the directory path, and a row of buttons (one per directory in the path). With the install of Ubunbtu 10.04 Nautilus 2.30.1 has just the button bar and no button to toggle to the text field. How do I get the control that was available before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change to text field, I use Ctrl-L.
I press ESC to go back to buttons.

Comment: 'tis pity that the documentation is so inaccessible. This is actually in the Desktop User Guide section 6.3.3 entitled "Using the Location Bar", but if you ask `yelp` for "location bar", 6.6.3 isn't one of the answers.

Comment: Would you add a link to:
http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.27/nautilus-location-bar.html.en in your answer.

Comment: I get a 404 from that link. How about http://www.rebelzero.com/tweaking/button-mode-always-for-nautilus-location-bar/255 ?